# How to get distinct values from mongoose model according to 2 fields?

Tags: mongoose

i am struck over problem in which I have mongoose model message like this:

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    by: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    to: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    body: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I want to get all the unique users in this model to which the message is sent by and received by any particular user.

```
const users = await Message.find({
   $or: [
     { by: req.user.userName },
     { to: req.user.userName },
   ],
 });
```

This is my query it gives me result but they are not distinct.
I may use

```
.distinct()
```

method of mongoose but how to use it on both "to" and "by" field.

It will be great if you can also give solution of how to sort it as we cant use sort() method with distinct() in mongoose.

Comment: have you tried aggregate?

Comment: Yes, I have but it's of no use here because it requires you to check 2 fields simultaneously.